# Django unable to parse POST data with webhooks

Tags: django, webhooks

I'm writing a webhook view to parse data from 3rd party. I have created a view with csrf_exempt decorator but Django is unable to parse the regular POST data (not JSON).

```
@csrf_exempt
def webhook(request):
    if request.method != "POST":
        return HttpResponse("Invalid Request.", status=400)

    print data = request.raw_post_data
    print request.POST
```

This will print the correct raw data (I tested with "domain=example.com&username=user") but it returns empty POST dict:

```
POST:<QueryDict: {}>
```

Any advice? I'm running Django 1.3

Comment: Traceback gives back: POST:<could not parse>,

Comment: Can you show the post data? From FireBug for example.

Comment: I have only used curl. E.g. curl -d "domain=domain=example.com&username=user" -X POST http://0.0.0.0:8000/newsletter/webhooks/

Comment: Incoming data should be ok as this also fails with Mailgun's webhooks which I'm building it for: http://www.postbin.org/11nexvi#k4k0b0

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure you have set the attribute name on inputs `<input type="text" name="input_name" />`